# How can I add an icon to the keyboard in my iPhone app, that would hide the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

How can I add an icon to the alphabetic keyboard in my iPhone app, that would hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .xib file, set the return key as you need, and set the delegate.
 And implement this method for resigning your keyboard on the done button click.(if it is a text field)

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)txt
{

    [urTextFld resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the keyboard itself, but you can add toolbar with a button. You can set the toolbar as the accessory view of the textfield/textview (whatever you are using). And you can hide the keyboard in the action method of the button on the toolbar.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
      [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```